# how to get the current open page url from the ads click?

Tags: android, ads

After clicking on any ad, how can we find out the link shown in that ad?
  If any APK link is provided in the ad from the Play Store, then it is installed or not.  How to find out

Using ads load method I open an ads. If user click any ads on the view it directs to another page. Now I want to get the url of the detected page. how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

The new Android feature allows you to get that link from one of the native properties of the instance of ad object (that is inherited from the main class). If I remember correctly, the property is called `url_text`.

You may want to use a built-in function `toUrl()` after you retrieve it, as the url is going to be in 128-bit unsigned array of characters

Comment: Because i'm  beginner .can u give you some more information. Or any example that I can understand. Thats would be good for me